# Resume activity after startActivity(Intent)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, start-activity

I'm implementing a code that verifies if there is an internet connection. If not, it starts the settings of the WiFi so the user can choose an Internet Connection.

The problem is that i want that when the user choose the connection and click back button, my activity verifies again if there is any connection to continue the execution, but it goes again to the `NETWORK_INACTIVE` dialog.

Here is the code where i start the new activity:

```
protected boolean hasNetworkConnection() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo wifi = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    NetworkInfo mobile = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

    try{
        if (!wifi.isConnected()){
            if(mobile==null || (mobile!=null && !mobile.isConnected())){
                onCreateDialog(NETWORK_INACTIVE).show();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("AEP41-Has Network", ""+e.getStackTrace());
    }
    return true;
}
@Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builter = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                AEP41Activity.this);

    switch (id) {

    case NETWORK_INACTIVE:
        builter.setCancelable(false);
        builter.setTitle("Erreur de Reseau");
        builter.setMessage("Aucune connexion internet trouve");
        builter.setNegativeButton("Sortir",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        AEP41Activity.this.finish();
                    }
                });
        builter.setNeutralButton("Choisir Connexion",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(
                                Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
                });
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return builter.create();
}
```

I've seen the option `startActivityForResult(Intent, int)` but i did't found any solution with the use of the Settings.

Is there any way of doing this?

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: In which method of the `Activity` are you calling `hasNetworkConnection()`?

Comment: @Squonk Its in the beginning of the onCreate()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This call isn't correct:

```
onCreateDialog(NETWORK_INACTIVE).show();
```

You should never call `onCreateDialog()` yourself. The Android framework does this for you. Instead of calling `onCreateDialog(NETWORK_INACTIVE).show();` you should do this:

```
showDialog(NETWORK_INACTIVE);
```

Comment: This is a temporary solution... And with the API 13 the showDialog(int) is deprecated... I just needed to put this to work so I could implement DialogFragment or create child classes of Dialog.

Comment: `showDialog()` works just fine. "deprecated" doesn't mean it doesn't work. It just means that it may go away in a future release. Try using my code and see if it helps.

Comment: Well in fact the dialog disappears if I use showDialog and doesn't if I use onCreateDialog... I suppose that is because of the onPrepareDialog that creates the default action of the Action Dialog buttons, in this case dismiss the dialog when cliqued. Thanks a lot for the help ;)

Answer (score 1):

I check for an active connection in `onResume()` and if there isn't one I have a method to create an `AlertDialog` as follows...

```
protected void createNetErrorDialog() {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("You need a network connection to use this application. Please turn on mobile network or Wi-Fi in Settings.")
    .setTitle("Unable to connect")
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("Settings",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    )
    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                MainActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }
    );
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

If the user hits the Cancel button I finish the `Activity` otherwise start Settings. If the user hits BACK in Settings, `onResume()` is called again and the network is checked again. This works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for your help but it seems that the dialog did'd disappears because of my call onCreateDialog().show(). I needed to call showDialog() instead.